# What is an example of elliptic curve $E'/ \Bbb{C}$ without CM whose rediction mod $p$ is supersingular?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/ \Bbb{Q}: y^2=x^3＋x$ has CM(complex multiplication) over $ \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-1})$.

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let it's reduction by $p$ be $E/  \Bbb{F}_p:y^2=x^3＋x$.

$E/  \Bbb{F}_7$ is supersingular because $ \sharp E[\Bbb{F}_7]=8$, and $E/  \Bbb{F}_5$ is turned out to be ordinary by counting rational points.

My question is, what is an example of elliptic curve $E'/ \Bbb{C}$ without CM($E'/ \Bbb{C}$ does not accept CM structure) whose rediction mod $p$,$E'/ \Bbb{ \overline{F_p}}$ is supersingular?

Comment: $y^2=x^3+x+7$ doesn't have CM according to https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/10616/a/1 If $\Bbb{Q}(E[n])$ isn't abelian over any imaginary quadratic subfield then $E$ doesn't have CM.

Comment: Thank you, your elliptic curve is what I was looking for because it does not have CM because its j invariant is not algebraic integer, and mod$7$ it it has $8$ rational points so supersingular.

Comment: You can get infinitely many examples for any starting curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ using Elkies' landmark result: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388985 (the proof is constructive).